# Is possible to add planned posts to Facebook page via API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebooksdk.net

I want to create simple app, console or ASP .NET to create bunch of planned posts to my Facebook Page. I know there are ways to post posts to Facebook Page via apps, but I am not sure if it is possible to create planned posts.

This is just idea, so I just want to learn if there is some automagic to do this, or it is super complicated. I don't want to neither invent wheel again from the scratch or make harakiri workaround if there is no such function in Facebook API (as I never saw that there).

Thanks in regards for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *"planned posts"* you mean scheduled posts where the post is only made public on a given date, then you are probably looking for [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/page/feed). Create a normal post but set `scheduled_publish_time` to a future date when you want other users to see it.

> scheduled_publish_time: Time when this post should go live, this can be
>   any date between ten minutes and six months from the time of the API
>   call.

Once you create scheduled posts, you can retrieve them using `/{page-id}/promotable_posts`. They do not show up under `/{page-id}/feed` before they are published.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I meant! Thanks